# Easy question on the partial derivative of a compound function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, u : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ both $C^{\infty}$ and $ g (x,y) = u(F(x,y))$. What is $\partial_x g$? And $\partial^2_{x,x} g$?

Let $ F(x,y) = (F_1(x,y), F_2(x,y)), u=u(a,b)$.
$$ DF =
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_x F_1 & \partial_y F_1\\
\partial_x F_2 & \partial_y F_2
\end{pmatrix}, \;
Du=
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_a u & \partial_b u
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How should I apply $ ((Du) \circ F) \cdot (DF) $ ?

Comment: You presume you do know the multi-varate chain rule, i.e., $D(u \circ F) = ((Du) \circ F) \cdot (DF)$, where $D$ is the differential operator?

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly

$$\partial_x g = \frac{ \partial u }{\partial F_1}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} + \frac{ \partial u }{\partial F_2}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}  $$
where $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial F_1} = \frac{ \partial u}{\partial a} \quad \mbox{ and } \frac{\partial u}{\partial F_2} = \frac{ \partial u}{\partial b}$$ where $u=u(a,b)$.
Similarly for the $y$.